# Calculating fluid pressure for ruptured eardrum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Your head is 15.5 feet below the surface of a pool. If the pressure inside your eardrum is 1.0 atm, what pressure will your eardrum have to withstand so it does not rupture?

NOTE: Assume water has a density of 1.00 g/cm$^3$.

I understand that P = $\rho$gh, and that I could calculate the pressure on the eardrum as P $\approx$ (1.00)(9.8)(15.5) $\approx$ 152

But I'm on unsure about two things:

1) What are the units for the pressure above? (should I convert 15.5 ft to m?)

2) What does the eardrum at 1.0 atm tell me about the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to SI units. Your $\rho$ and $g$ already are (but watch out for the power of ten prefixes), convert feet to meters.
Of course the 1 atm inside the eardrum merely compensates what that unit stands for: the atmosphere. So we really need to calculate only the water pressure.

Comment: So the 1.0 atm can just be considered extraneous information?